# drop down menu form i would like to add the link to work with my ajax script?

Tags: ajax, drop-down-menu

my site is : http://server1.bioprotege-inc.net/permanent_Files/digichat_admin_panel/#Home

the link that says "home" drops down the content that i specified what id like to do but cant get to work is use one of the options on the drop down menu to drop the same content as the link home does but i cant get it to work like that and suggestions?

```
// JavaScript Document



$(document).ready(function(){


    $("#Home").click(function(){
                Load_ajax_page("Content_Files/Home.html");
    });


    $("#Chat").click(function(){
                Load_ajax_page("Content_Files/Chat.html");
    });


    $("#Rules_List").click(function(){
                Load_ajax_page("Content_Files/Rules_List.html");
    });


    $("#The_Team").click(function(){
                Load_ajax_page("Content_Files/The_Team.html");
    });


    $("#Forums").click(function(){
                Load_ajax_page("Content_Files/Forums.html");
    });

});



function Load_ajax_page(url){


    //this is a jquery method to make a ajax request
    $.post(url,"",function (data){
        //this is the place where the data is returned by the request
        //remove loading and add the data
        $("#response").html(data);
    });

}






HTML CODE NOW FOR DROPDOWN MENU:


<form onclick="">
<select onchange="window.open(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,'_top')" style="width:582px; height:25px;">
<option value="#">Enter Free Hosted Sites:</option>
<option value="#"></option>
<option value="#Home">Hosted1 - Shadow Hunters</option>
<option value="http://www.google.com">Hosted2</option>
<option>Hosted3</option>
<option>Hosted4</option>
</select>
</form>

<br />

<div id="response"></div>
```

Comment: we need to see your script buddy! Show us some codes! =D

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
 

 $("#Home").click(function(){
                Load_ajax_page("Content_Files/Home.html");
 });


 $("#Chat").click(function(){
                Load_ajax_page("Content_Files/Chat.html");
 });


 $("#Rules_List").click(function(){
                Load_ajax_page("Content_Files/Rules_List.html");
 });


 $("#The_Team").click(function(){
                Load_ajax_page("Content_Files/The_Team.html");
 });


 $("#Forums").click(function(){
                Load_ajax_page("Content_Files/Forums.html");
 });

});



function Load_ajax_page(url){

Comment: Please... put your code inside the question. Just click the "edit" button.

Comment: Please post your html code too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
try{
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
catch(ee){
try{
xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
}
catch(e){
try{
xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
catch(E){
xmlhttp = false;
}
}
}
div_base = "";
valor = 0;
function abre(arquivo,metodo,div){
div_base = div;
valor++;
xmlhttp.open(metodo,arquivo+"?valor="+valor);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=response
xmlhttp.send(null)
}
function response() {
nova_div = div_base;
document.getElementById(nova_div).innerHTML="<div style='top:50%;left:50%;position:absolute;'>Loading...</div>"
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4){
document.getElementById(nova_div).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText
}
}
</script>

<form>
<select name="menu">
<option onclick="javascript: abre('Content_Files/Home.html','GET','response');">Home</option>
<option onclick="javascript: abre('Content_Files/Chat.html','GET','response');">Chat</option>
<option onclick="javascript: abre('Content_Files/Rules_List.html','GET','response');">Rules_List</option>
<option onclick="javascript: abre('Content_Files/The_Team.html','GET','response');">The_Team</option>
<option onclick="javascript: abre('Content_Files/Forums.html','GET','response');">Forums</option>
</select>
</form>
<br /><br />
<div id="response"></div>
```

Comment: nope, it does not work, it opens up the page on a new browser instead of using the ajax to open up in the div area without refreshing

Comment: <option value="#Home" id="Home">Home</option>  does my option still stay like this? when selected it just stays blank no activity with changed home ajax script file

Comment: New code... I've tested this one... It works perfectly. The functionality is ok.

Comment: your code makes no sence, i have a working ajax code that works with a menu, im looking to add that code to a drop down menu as stated in the description.

Comment: First: It took work to research this for you. Do not be ungrateful! Second: My code is working, because it displays the page correctly inside the div. Your code "works" but does not display the site in the div. That is, does not work. Otherwise you would not have asked for help. Third: Do your homework. Adapt it to your needs. Otherwise, soon will be making the entire site for you. = D

Comment: my code works , i use it on another wbesite, what it doesn't do is work in a dropdown, and i didn't ask to remake the code, i simply asked how to use the ajax link <a title="Home" href="#Home" id="Home">Home</a> and make it work inside the <option value="#"></option> code.